# php upload file into the folder

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload multiple images into the folder using php  . The code can print out the file names which means I get the files but now it does not upload them and I get no error : below is my code

```
<?php 
    $target = "image_uploads/";
    if(isset($_FILES['FILE_NAME'])){
        foreach($_FILES['FILE_NAME']['tmp_name']as $key => $error ){
           print_r($key);
           $file_upload = $key.$_FILES['FILE_NAME']['name'][$key];
           #print image names
           echo $file_upload.'</br>';
          move_uploaded_file($file_upload,$target);    
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hey, if you're sending a multiple file, `$_FILES` should be an array of files and should be used like this :
`$_FILES['FILE_NAME'][0]['tmp_name']` for the first one etc.

Answer (score 2):

In target you have to give the file name too. Please use the code below,

```
$target = "image_uploads/";
if(isset($_FILES['FILE_NAME'])){
    foreach($_FILES['FILE_NAME']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
        print_r($key);
        $file_upload = $key.$_FILES['FILE_NAME']['name'][$key];
        print image names
        echo $file_upload.'</br>';
        move_uploaded_file($file_upload,$target.$_FILES['FILE_NAME']['name']);    
    }
}
```

Comment: @humphrey: whether it is coming inside foreach loop or not? give some space in foreach as

Comment: @humphery: name of the file is $_FILES['FILE_NAME']['name']. i have edited. please use that

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the foreach loop.

```
foreach ($_FILES['FILE_NAME']['tmp_name'] as $key => $val) {
    // this loops through the tmp_name of $_FILES['FILE_NAME']
    // which is a string
}
```

I think you meant something like:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $index => $fileArray) {
    $tmpName = $fileArray['tmp_name'];
    echo "File at key $index is temporarily uploaded at $tmpName";
}
```

The code above will loop through all uploaded files and print it's current filename.

Comment: thanks but also mine does but the problem is it doe not upload to the folder

Comment: have you checked `is_writable($target)`, to check if php can write to the folder?

Comment: @ChrisF no but I had another code which could do upload but all i want now to start my own code so that I understand nicely (thanks Chris )

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that your target folder is not writable.

I also think, that the cause of which you're not getting errors is, that you have the following:

```
print_r($key);
```

Yous should have:

```
print_r($error);
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this :

1. The target folder must exist before trying to move the file from temp location to the target and must also be writable
2. the move_uploaded_file takes the second argument as the file name followed by the directory name, so it can be something like : target folder/user.file.name.ext
3. If you are uploading multiple files, then the $_FILES must be accessed as shown in the link : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php
4. for the php error messages that you may encounter, here is a list : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php